# Web Firebase Google SignIn doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to web development and am trying to create an app that right now allows you to sign in using Firebase Authentication and the app will display your name. I have been following the Codelab that Firebase offers online to create this basic functionality but I cannot figure out why I am not able to detect that someone has signed in. Here is my initFirebase function:

```
LoginClient.prototype.initFirebase = function() {
  // Shortcuts to Firebase SDK features.
  this.auth = firebase.auth();
  this.database = firebase.database();
  this.storage = firebase.storage();
  // Initiates Firebase auth and listen to auth state changes.
  this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged.bind(this));
};
```

Within this I am using onAuthStateChanged to listen for the auth state change and execute the following function that I have written:

```
LoginClient.prototype.onAuthStateChanged = function(user) {
  if(user){
    //window.open("userdash.html");
    console.log("onAuthStateChanged works")
    /*this.userNameDisplay.innerText = "Hello " + user.displayName + "!";
    window.alret("Hello " + user.displayName + "!");*/
    //this.userNameDisplay.removeAttribute('hidden');
    this.userNameDisplay.textContent= user.displayName;
    this.userNameDisplay.removeAttribute('hidden');
    this.signInButton.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    this.googleSignInButton.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    this.createAccountButton.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
  }else{
    this.userNameDisplay.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    this.signInButton.removeAttribute('hidden');
    this.googleSignInButton.removeAttribute('hidden');
    this.createAccountButton.removeAttribute('hidden');
 }
};
```

The function will detect that there is a user and then display the name of the person who signed in. So what I want to happen is for me to press a button that triggers the following google sign in function:

```
LoginClient.prototype.googleSignIn = function(){
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  this.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  console.log("Signed in google");
};
```

which will allow a user to signin off the popup window that is created. Once they have successfully signed in, the auth.onAuthStateChanged listener will be triggered and cause the above onAuthStateChanged function to be called. However what is currently happening is that the googleSignIn function is called and a popup window is created but before I can authenticate on the popup window, the page reloads. Once I finish signing in successfully on the popup window the onAuthStateChanged function fails to be called. Can anyone help me figure out why the page reloads when I try to sign in?

Comment: I don't see any code that should trigger a page reload. Are you certain you can [reproduce the problem with just this code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What does your button click handler look like? Are you missing e.preventDefault()?